# Is Node.js ready for business critical applications?

Tags: web-applications, node.js, enterprise, mission-critical

I was just reading [More proof that enterprises love Node.js](http://gigaom.com/cloud/more-proof-that-enterprises-love-node-js/) and wondering:

> **Should enterprise consider using nodejs for business critical
>   applications?**

It seems cloud computing companies like [Joyent](http://www.joyent.com/) are fully on to it. Even Microsoft have started supporting nodejs on their Azure platform. I would like to know how seriously should we consider nodejs for enterprise application? Is it ready for mission critical applications?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Hell Yeah!!.. Understanding what Node.js is very important tho. A lot of large companies are already making a move towards using Node.js in many different ways

Other Examples

Linkedin - http://venturebeat.com/2011/08/16/linkedin-node/

Yahoo - http://developer.yahoo.com/blogs/ydn/posts/2011/11/yahoo-announces-cocktails-%E2%80%93-shaken-not-stirred/

Ebay - http://www.ebaytechblog.com/2011/11/30/announcing-ql-io/

Comment: mission critical applications in the enterprise usually means financial applications. And financial applications in the enterprise usually means a lot of mission critical number crunching that can't be messed up. Node is not a language for that. Most web stuff unless all your business is online is not mission critical. But OK maybe it is solid for that. But need better proof before I would think it is OK handling my financials.

Comment: I think nowadays thats dependent on the developers building those applications more than a language. Node is not a language, its a framework which solves a problem in a particular way, if it fits your problem set, use it.  Thats the way it is with languages or framework, they are very good at solving certain problems and aren't good at others. I haven't used node for financial stuff neither have I read anything about it not being a good fit for it or that its a perfect fit for those use-cases. So I can neither dispute or agree with you here.

Comment: Well, see the answer below, I am not sure if that qualifies as completely financial tho.

Answer (score 1):

Dow Jones is using it for quite a few products now: WSJ Mobile, WSJ Portfolio, Streaming Stories, DJ X, and a few smaller projects. Within this next year almost all our web apps and pages will be on node =) We are constantly beefing up our node stack.